# O que é a assinatura unicode (BOM)?

Tags: php, html, unicode

Reparei que as vezes o dreamweaver coloca `assinatura unicode (BOM)` em algumas páginas php's, tenho que retirar a maioria das vezes para que não apareça um espaçamento na página de exibição e não sei bem para que serve `assinatura unicode (BOM)` vocês poderiam me explicar?

Comment: @DBX8 mas acredito que as resposta daquela pergunta podem responder essa pergunta.

Comment: ANSI é com um I só; ASCII é com dois I. ;-)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

O marcador BOM é um indicar de ordem dos bytes em um arquivo de texto, para cada par de 2 bytes, no caso de unicode-16 e para o grupo de 4 bytes no unicode-32.

Esse marcador vem exclusivamente no início do arquivo.

BOM significa ***"Byte Order Mark"***, que em português seria algo como **"Marca de ordenação de bytes"**.

**EDIT**

Também existe BOM para unicode-8, mas o seu uso não é recomendado, uma vez, que só existe uma ordenação possível para caracteres compostos por um único byte.

**EDIT** Print da [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), mostrando os marcadores (já que não é possível montar tabelas aqui no SO)

[image: Tabela de BOM]

Origem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Comment: Byte Order Mark, marca de ordem de bytes, e não Binary Order Mark.

Comment: Lá vai...: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sv8XehRa-cg (sorry, não resisti).

Comment: @Bacco HUahuhua! Boa... ou seja, a fêmea do BOM. (só pra entrar no espírito da coisa =)

Comment: Esse BOM é mais usado em sistemas Windows, certo?

Answer (score 14):

O BOM (byte order mark, marca de ordem de bytes) foi criado para solucionar um problema do UTF-16 (e também do UTF-32, embora este formato seja pouco usado para salvar arquivos).

Como cada caracter em UTF-16 é composto por 2 bytes (ou em casos mais raros por um par de unidades de 2 bytes cada), existe a possibilidade de ordená-los de maneiras diferentes: byte 1, byte 2; ou byte 2, byte 1 (sobre a ordem dos bits, ninguém discute, pelo menos...). Então arquiteturas little-endian preferirão usar UTF-16LE (LE = little endian), que tem a ordem “byte 2, byte 1” que é a mais natural para o processador. E arquiteturas big-endian preferirão usar UTF-16BE.

Para diferenciar os dois tipos de UTF-16, usa-se o BOM no começo do arquivo, que é um caracter que não pode ser confundido com seu “inverso”, portanto ao lê-lo será possível descobrir qual é a ordem dos bytes do resto do arquivo.

Já o UTF-8 foi elaborado de maneira diferente, onde a ordem dos bytes não depende da arquitetura do computador. Por isso, muitos consideram desnecessário usar BOM em arquivos UTF-8.

O BOM, que em UTF-16 ocupa 2 bytes, ao ser codificado em UTF-8 toma a forma de 3 bytes. Por isso alguns programas, apesar da não-recomendação de usar BOM em UTF-8 acabaram por adotá-lo mesmo assim, pois quando abrirem um arquivo e encontrarem aqueles 3 bytes especiais, saberão que provavelmente se trata de um arquivo UTF-8 (porque é muito raro um texto começar com `ï»¿`, que é como aparece o BOM se for lido como a codificação cp1252).

Agora, se você deve ou não usar BOM nos seus arquivos, o debate fica um pouco filosófico, porque existem prós e contras...

Answer (score 12):

`BOM` significa [Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

No nosso mundo as pessoas não conseguem se entender sobre várias coisas, inclusive se os bits de menor valor de um *byte* devem ser alinhados à esquerda ou a direita. Acredite, há discussões acaloradas e cheias de agressões pessoais sobre qual forma é melhor.

Com certos *encodings* acontece algo parecido. Alguns caracteres são representados por mais de um *byte*. Em UTF-32, por exemplo, são utilizados quatro *bytes* por caractere. Existem pessoas que preferem que os *bytes* com valores menores sejam alinhados a esquerda ou a direita em cada caractere.

Como não é possível adotar uma ou outra forma como a universal, às vezes a gente precisa informar a um *parser* a ordem em que os *bytes* devem ser lidos. A gente faz isso utilizando o `BOM`. Se você não informar o `BOM`, o parser tem que literalmente adivinhar a forma de leitura. Por isso que, sem ele, às vezes os textos ficam "quebrados".

É comum o `BOM` de um texto ser indicado pelo pré-âmbulo, que são os três primeiros *bytes* de um texto. O *parser* os utiliza para determinar qual é o *encoding* utilizado.

Como notado pelo DBX8 na resposta dele, isso deveria ser irrelevante para o UTF-8, que utiliza apenas um *byte* por caractere. A única vantagem de se informar o `BOM` do UTF-8 é que isso ajuda o *parser* a reconhecer o *encoding* utilizado.

Comment: Correção: ordem dos bytes, não dos bits. E no UTF-8 não existe esse problema, cada unidade tem apenas 1 byte, com a possibilidade de "extensões" serem colocadas depois, mas com uma ordem bem definida. O BOM no UTF-8 acaba servindo mais para indicar que o arquivo é UTF-8 do que realmente para indicar a ordem (seu propósito original).

Answer (score 10):

UTF-8 em conjunto com [`BOM`](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marca_de_ordem_de_byte)(*Byte order mark*) é codificado com os bytes `EF BB BF` no início do arquivo. Não há diferença, **pelo menos não oficial** entre *UTF-8* e *UTF-8 com BOM*. Enquanto há utilização, de acordo com o [`Padrão Unicode`](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.2.0/ch03.pdf), o *Byte order mark* para arquivos UTF-8 **não é recomendado**.

Na seção **3.10 Unicode Encoding Schemes**, item *`D95`* diz, em tradução livre:

> O seu uso no início de um fluxo de dados UTF-8 não é necessário nem
>   recomendado pelo Unicode Standard, mas a sua presença não afeta a
>   conformidade com o esquema de codificação UTF-8.

Comment: A ordem dos bytes não é variável em UTF-8. Mas claro, pode haver o problema de descobrir que o texto está em UTF-8 para começo de conversa...

Comment: Verdade. Vou corrigir minha resposta.

Answer (score 6):

Você pode corrigir esse problema como demonstrado abaixo:

1. http://www.melhorweb.com.br/artigo/5-Problemas-de-espacamento-e-acentuacao-no-Dreamweaver.htm
2. http://forum.imasters.com.br/topic/511360-desativar-assinatura-unicode-bom/

**O que é o BOM?**

A marca de ordem de byte (BOM) é um caractere Unicode usado para denotar a extremidade (ordem de bytes) de um arquivo de texto ou fluxo de dados, com código é U+FEFF. Seu uso é opcional e, se usado, deve aparecer no começo do fluxo de texto.

Além do seu uso tradicional, esse caractere também pode indicar em qual das diferentes representações Unicode o texto está codificado.1 Tendo em vista que o Unicode pode ser codificado tanto em 16 quanto 32 bits, o leitor de texto Unicode deve saber em que formato o texto sendo lido está codificado.

Fonte: http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marca_de_ordem_de_byte

Comment: "esse caractere também pode indicar em qual das diferentes representações Unicode o texto está codificado" Acho que não... se ele encontrar um `FF FE 00 00` como ele poderia diferenciar entre um UTF-32 e um UTF-16 onde o primeiro caractere é nulo?

Comment: @mgibsonbr, tens razão acerca desta ambiguidades. Na maioria dos casos o BOM é suficiente para determinar o sistema de codificação usado, e a generalidade das ferramentas interepreta o FEFF0000 como utf-32 (o que dá uma enorme dor de cabeça para os utf-16 começados por nulo -- casos rarissimos mas que já me aconteceu) (Detesto BOMs :)