# O que acontece quando converto String para um array de bytes?

Tags: java, c, array, string, byte

Eu tenho:

```
String msg = "Texto a ser encriptado";
byte array[] = msg.getBytes();
```

**O que acontece quando converto a string em um array de bytes?**

Estou preocupado com uma aplicação que estou desenvolvendo. Preciso enviar dados encriptados de um servidor para um sistema embarcado. O motivo da minha preocupação é a codificação dos caracteres, já que minha aplicação embarcada tem um firmware escrito em C e uso `char` para armazenar os dados recebidos.  **Terei algum problema com a codificação?**

Caso seja necessário, posso colocar trechos de código da minha aplicação.

Comment: Se você tem uma string Unicode e você a converte de/para uma mesma codificação específica (digamos, UTF-8) então a sequência de bytes resultante será sempre a mesma. Detalhe: verifique se a função "getBytes" da sua plataforma permite que você especifique a codificação, evite [métodos que usam a codificação padrão do sistema](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes()), pois isso pode não ser portável. E obviamente, não use [métodos quebrados](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes(int,%20int,%20byte[],%20int)).

Comment: Avelino, a minha resposta ou a do @mgibsonbr te satisfizeram? Se sim, poderia aceitar uma delas? Caso contrário, há alguma coisa que ainda queira esclarecer?

Comment: @VictorStafusa, acabei por aceitar a sua resposta como correta por demonstrar como devo utilizar o `.getBytes();` de forma mais apropriada. Mas as duas respostas me foram muito úteis (dei +1 para ambas) e também muito boas. Perdão a demora, estou de TCC e tive que analisá-las com mais calma (e mais tempo).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bem, eis o que diz o [javadoc do método `getBytes()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes--):

> **getBytes**
>
> `public byte[] getBytes()`
>
> Encodes this `String` into a sequence of bytes using the platform's default charset, storing the result into a new byte array.
>
> The behavior of this method when this string cannot be encoded in the default [charset](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) is unspecified. The [`CharsetEncoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetEncoder.html) class should be used when more control over the encoding process is required.
>
> **Returns:**
>
> The resultant byte array
>
> **Since:**
>
> JDK1.1

Traduzindo para o português:

> **getBytes**
>
> `public byte[] getBytes()`
>
> Codifica esta `String` em uma sequência de *bytes* utilizando o [*charset*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) padrão da plataforma, armazenando o resultado em um novo *array* de *bytes*.
>
> O comportamento deste método quando esta *string* não pode ser codificada no *charset* padrão não é especificado. A classe [`CharsetEncoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetEncoder.html) deve ser utilizada quando mais controle sobre o processo de codificação é requerido.
>
> **Retorna:**
>
> O *array* de *bytes* resultante
>
> **Desde:**
>
> JDK1.1

**Ou seja, este método não irá servir para o seu propósito! E sim, você poderá ter problemas de codificação.**

Uma forma de melhorar um pouco a situação é usar os métodos [`getBytes(String charsetName)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes-java.lang.String-) ou [`getBytes(Charset charset)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes-java.nio.charset.Charset-), que permitem você utilizar um *charset* bem definido e evitar confiar no *charset* padrão da plataforma. Mas ainda assim, no caso da `String` não puder ser codificada no `Charset` especificado, o comportamento ainda é não-especificado (ou seja, indefinido). Normalmente isso lhe será suficiente, se você garantir que todas as `String`s utilizadas sempre poderão ser codificadas no *charset* escolhido, ou então se você simplesmente não se importar com as que não puderem.

Com isso, o seu código seria algo assim:

```java
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ConversaoSimples {

    // Método main só para testar o método converte.
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String minhaString = "João comeu pão com feijão.";
        byte[] bytes = converte(minhaString);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bytes));
        try {
            System.out.println(new String(bytes, "UTF-8"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException x) {
            throw new AssertionError(x);
        }
    }

    // Método que faz a conversão.
    private static byte[] converte(String str) {
        try {
            return str.getBytes("UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException x) {
            throw new AssertionError(x);
        }
    }
}
```

Eis a saída:

```
[74, 111, -61, -93, 111, 32, 99, 111, 109, 101, 117, 32, 112, -61, -93, 111, 32, 99, 111, 109, 32, 102, 101, 105, 106, -61, -93, 111, 46]
João comeu pão com feijão.
```

Porém, se o detalhe que as *strings* que não podem ser codificadas com o *charset* especificado resultarem em *arrays* de *bytes* com comportamento um pouco indefinido fizer diferença para você, o melhor é usar a classe 
[`CharsetEncoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetEncoder.html). Uma vez que esta é uma classe abstrata (e não faz sentido você criar subclasses dela), para obter instâncias você vai precisar usar [o método `newEncoder()` da classe `Charset`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#newEncoder--). A própria classe `Charset` também é abstrata, e para obter uma instância dela, use [o método estático `forName(String charsetName)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#forName-java.lang.String-).

Após adquirir a instância do `CharsetEncoder`, você pode querer reconfigurá-lo com alguns dos seus métodos que retornam `CharsetEncoder`. Estes métodos modificam o `CharsetEncoder` e o retornam. Entratanto, você não precisa modificá-lo, a configuração padrão vai substituir os caracteres desconhecidos por pontos de interrogação.

Após ter o `CharsetEncoder` devidamente configurado, use um dos métodos `encode` dele. O mais simples de usar é o método [`encode(CharBuffer in)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharsetEncoder.html#encode-java.nio.CharBuffer-), que recebe um `CharBuffer` e devolve um `ByteBuffer`. Para obter uma instância do `CharBuffer`, use [o método estático `wrap(CharSequence csq)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/CharBuffer.html#wrap-java.lang.CharSequence-) passando como parâmetro a sua `String`.

Após obter o `ByteBuffer`, você pode usar [o método `array()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#array--) para obter um *array* de *bytes*.

O *array* de *bytes* obtido do `ByteBuffer` pode vir com alguns zeros no final, pois o tamanho dele deverá ser uma potência de 2 (que são usadas para balancear desempenho com utilização de memória). Estes zeros são valores não preenchidos do *buffer* alocado. Você necessitará retirar estes zeros do final do *array*.

Por fim, o código fica complicadinho:

```java
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.CharBuffer;
import java.nio.charset.CharacterCodingException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.charset.CharsetEncoder;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ConversaoComplicada {

    // Método main só para testar o método converte.
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String minhaString = "João comeu pão com feijão.";
        byte[] bytes = converte(minhaString);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(bytes));
        try {
            System.out.println(new String(bytes, "UTF-8"));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException x) {
            throw new AssertionError(x);
        }
    }

    // Método que faz a conversão.
    private static byte[] converte(String str) {
        try {
            Charset c = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
            CharsetEncoder ce = c.newEncoder();

            // Se você quiser modificar o CharsetEncoder, faça aqui. Por exemplo:
            // ce.replaceWith(...);

            CharBuffer cb = CharBuffer.wrap(str);
            ByteBuffer bb = ce.encode(cb);
            byte[] b = bb.array();
            return cortaZeros(b);
        } catch (CharacterCodingException x) {
            throw new AssertionError(x);
        }
    }

    private static byte[] cortaZeros(byte[] array) {
        if (array[array.length - 1] != 0) return array;
        int inicio = 0, fim = array.length;
        while (inicio != fim && inicio != fim - 1) {
            int m = (inicio + fim) / 2;
            if (array[m] == 0) {
                fim = m;
            } else {
                inicio = m;
            }
        }
        int tamanho = array[inicio] == 0 ? inicio : inicio + 1;
        byte[] resultado = new byte[tamanho];
        System.arraycopy(array, 0, resultado, 0, tamanho);
        return resultado;
    }
}
```

Eis a saída:

```
[74, 111, -61, -93, 111, 32, 99, 111, 109, 101, 117, 32, 112, -61, -93, 111, 32, 99, 111, 109, 32, 102, 101, 105, 106, -61, -93, 111, 46]
João comeu pão com feijão.
```

Ah sim, eu estou supondo que a sua `String` não tem nenhum caractere zero nela, especialmente no final dela. Se isso acontecer, este algoritmo acima ficará ainda mais complicadinho.

Comment: +1, em especial pela última parte, bem detalhada. Entretanto, eu recomendaria a qualquer um que não esteja dando suporte a um sistema legado simplesmente evitar codificações de caracteres que não sejam capazes de representar *todos* os caracteres Unicode.

Answer (score 4):

Uma "string" é um **tipo abstrato de dados**, representando uma sequência finita de "caracteres". A implementação desse tipo numa plataforma qualquer - e mesmo a interpretação semântica do que é um "caractere" - varia de linguagem pra linguagem, de plataforma pra plataforma.

Eu poderia discorrer sobre o assunto, mas para manter a resposta simples vamos assumir que sua linguagem dê suporte apropriado a caracteres [Unicode](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode), e que possua métodos para converter strings de/para [codificações de caracteres](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_caracteres) (*character encodings*) bem definidos. Então temos o seguinte:

- Uma sequência bem definida de [*"Unicode Code Points"*](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ponto_de_c%C3%B3digo) é representada em memória na forma do tipo string. Se esse tipo a representa internamente como *code units*, *code points*, bytes, etc, não importa. Se ele representa caracteres [fora do BMP](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plano_(Unicode)) como um ou dois caracteres, não importa. O que importa é que cada string represente "inambiguamente" (nem sei se essa palavra existe) toda e qualquer sequência válida de *code points*.
- Uma codificação de caracteres representa cada *code point* como uma sequência bem definida de bytes. Algumas codificações possuem ambiguidades que precisam ser resolvidas (como [a ordem dos bytes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9940/215) que representam cada caractere), mas que eu saiba todas possuem uma correspondência de um para um entre *code point* e sequência de bytes.

  Em particular, a [UTF-8](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) foi projetada para ter um alto grau de compatibilidade com sistemas baseados em ASCII (1 caractere ASCII vira 1 byte com a mesma representação - incluindo o terminador nulo - enquanto 1 caractere não-ASCII vira dois ou mais bytes codificados de tal forma que nenhum deles se confunda com um caractere ASCII, a ordem deles importe e fique bem evidente qual é o "primeiro" e quais são os demais).

Logo, ao converter da representação em memória da string para uma representação em bytes, a mesma string sempre gerará a mesma sequência de bytes, e a mesma sequência de bytes sempre produzirá a mesma string original.

Ok, e quanto ao código em C, especificamente? De acordo com [essas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/881894/520779) [duas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13454183/520779) perguntas no SOen, o padrão ANSI C não determina que o tipo `char` possua exatamente 8 bits, mas que seja de um tipo capaz de representar todos os caracteres em um determinado conjunto, denominado *"execution character set"*. O que exatamente é esse conjunto, não sei dizer.

Não tenho experiência com C, nem soube interpretar 100% as informações apresentadas nas perguntas linkadas, mas acho que é seguro assumir que um "array de `char`s" em C **não** é necessariamente capaz de representar toda e qualquer sequência de *Unicode Code Points*. Se sua aplicação embarcada pretende manipular strings, é necessário procurar saber quais recursos seu ambiente suporta para tratar de codificações de caracteres e Unicode.

[Nessa página](http://unicodebook.readthedocs.org/en/latest/programming_languages.html) (em inglês) há uma demonstração dos diversos recursos para manipulação de strings Unicode nas principais linguagens populares. Mas se você está interessado particularmente no C, talvez valha a pena abrir uma pergunta separada buscando uma forma correta de se tratar strings *na sua plataforma específica* (importante, do contrário a pergunta ficará muito ampla - ou, mesmo que "respondível", não se aplicará necessariamente ao seu caso particular).