# Por que aparece este erro ï»¿quando incluo um ficheiro php

Tags: php, html, include, syntax-error

Tenho o problema do erro `ï»¿` sempre que tento incluir um ficheiro.

Estou a trabalhar numa aplicação. Ao tentar incluir um outro ficheiro em php simplesmente cria um espaço na página, onde aparece os carácteres: `ï»¿`.

Agradeço ajuda tão logo possível.

Comment: Se a resposta resolveu o problema marque-a como correta, se não sabe como fazer veja um tutorial: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/3635

Comment: @Bacco eu pensei nisso e admito que muitas respostas no SOpt deveriam seguir a sua sugestão, a questão é que lá a pergunta é pra quem já sabe o que é BOM e pra que ele serve e o que muda sem, aqui a pergunta é "como remover", acho que ao meu ver está é a diferença entre ambas.

Comment: @Bacco só vou deixar os meus comentários 1 e 2, porque um deles é pra orientar o AP e o outro é pra defender o porque reabrir, já que acabei votando por isto, mas se permanecer fechada também não vejo problema, seguindo pela sua sugestão de manter a linkagem entre ambas :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento concordo. Deixe esse último também, aí fica tudo certo, assim quem chegar depois vai saber que tivemos uma conversa sobre os diferentes pontos de vista sobre o fechamento :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isto ocorre porque o arquivo incluido está salvo no formato UTF8 com BOM ao invés de UTF8 sem BOM, todos ficheiros devem ser salvos com *ut8 **sem** BOM*, veja como fazer isto com:

- Usando notepad++:

  [image: utf8 sem bom notepad++]
- Usando Sublime Text:

  [image: utf8 sublime sublimetext]
- Vim:

  Defina o `fileencoding` como `utf8` (acredito que já fique sem BOM)

  ```
  :set fileencoding=utf8
  :w arquivo.txt
  ```

Pra entender a diferenças entre UTF8 com e sem BOM, leia:

- [Para que serve assinatura unicode (BOM)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/9940/3635)

Comment: Ok já funcionou.