# Html.Raw devo usar em toda aplicação?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-helpers

Olá em todas PartialView do meu site, tive que colocar Html.Raw para resolver problemas com acentuação ( mesmo no Head colocar UTF-8 e no web.config globalização ) somente com Html.Raw resolveu, minha dúvida é posso colocar em todos campos ( Title,Description e etc ) sem comprometer a performance, já que não deixa de ser um HtmlHelpers??? grato.

Answer (score 0):

Quando eu tive problema com acentuação nas Views do Asp Net MVC, eu simplesmente salvei os arquivos específicos que estava com esse problema com a codificação [UTF-8 com BOM](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9940).

Veja um pequeno exemplo:

[image: Salvar arquivo com codificação específica no VS Studio]

Aqui [nesse link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dxfdkfke.aspx) explica como salvar ou abrir um documento com uma codificação específica.

Particularmente, acho horrível a ideia de usar qualquer função para corrigir codificação, tendo a possibilidade de corrigir através do salvamento do arquivo com a codificação correta, uma vez que você vai ter que trocar cada trecho do código na mão.

Comment: Então Wallace eu já tinha verificado o encoding desta forma e estão todas um UTF-8 isto só acontece nas PartialView nas Views não acontece isto, então resolvi colocando um Html.Raw no retorno do Banco só assim resolveu. Valeu !!

Comment: @WeberSP UTF-8 com BOM ou sem BOM? É por isso que fiz questão de falar isso na resposta. Quando tive o problema, algumas views minhas (especialmente as que foram geradas por scaffold), ficaram com UTF-8 **SEM BOM**. Eu precisei salvar como UTF-8 com BOM para resolver. BOM é Byte Order Marker.

Comment: Wallace Maxters valeu pela dica não conhecia esta forma de codificação sem e com, mas mesmo assim não resolveu... mesmo usando o Notepad++ e o Save do Visual. Abraços.